# Getting the height of an ImageSource in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, image, bitmap, height

In my Silverlight control, I am loading my background image from a stream:

```
   BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
   img.SetSource(stream);

   Image background = new Image();
   background.Source = img;
```

How can I find out the **height** of the bitmap image that was loaded from stream? None of the usual suspects (e.g., Property, DependencyProperty) seem to be available, neither on img, nor on background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try:

```
img.Measure();
img.DesiredSize.Height;
```

Comment: Almost, but you got me on the right track. 

Here's what works for me:

1. Create an event handler for the Loaded event.
2. img.Measure( new Size(sizeX, sizeY));
3. img.ActualHeight contains the size in pixels!

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you.