# Change the orientation based on Image width and height

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have few images thats being displayed, now there are some images where the width of the image is greater than the height of the image.

Say: `image.GetWidth() > image.GetHeight();`

`display the image in landscape mode, 
  else 
 display the image in portrait mode.`

I have searched,and could not find any resource that will help me in this case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please not that i am on WP8.

**EDIT**

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
grid.Height = height; //set height
grid.Width = width; //set width
grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
Image img = new Image();
img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
img.Source = source;
```

Comment: What is your question? do you want to test whether `image.Width > image.Height`?

Comment: @agarwaen yes, before its being rendered on the screen and then change the orientation according to that

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372559/keep-same-layout-when-orientation-changes

Comment: @Sajeetharan that link gives us information about the orientation, but not how to dynamically get the width and height of image at runtime

Comment: @user2056563 Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966696/getting-the-height-of-an-imagesource-in-silverlight

Comment: I think u missed RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5".

Answer (score 1):

Try this,First add composite transform to image

```
        <Image Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="compositeTransform"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

then check Height width(hope you have height width) of image and set composite transform rotation as per height width. Use -90 degree or +90 degree as per your requirement.

```
        image.Height = 300;
        image.Width = 400;
        if (image.Height > image.Width)
        {
            compositeTransform.Rotation = 0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            compositeTransform.Rotation = 90.00;
        }
        image.Source =(ImageSource) new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("2011-Chrysler-300-Model-09-1024x1280.jpg");
```

For Code Behind first add composite transform then set it to image

```
    CompositeTransform transform = new CompositeTransform();
    transform.CenterX = 0.5;
    transform.CenterY = 0.5;
    image.RenderTransform = transform;
```

Then check Height width(hope you have height width) of image and set composite transform rotation as per height width. Use -90 degree or +90 degree as per your requirement.

```
        image.Height = 300;
        image.Width = 400;
        if (image.Height > image.Width)
        {
            transform.Rotation = 0.0;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotation = 90.00;
        }
        image.Source =(ImageSource) new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("2011-Chrysler-300-Model-09-1024x1280.jpg");
```

Comment: Please see my edit, help me to modify according to my requirement

Comment: Try this, Add                                           
CompositeTransform transform = new CompositeTransform(); transform.CenterX = 0.5;
transform.CenterY = 0.5;
image.RenderTransform = transform;                                   and now just replace tranform in if-else statement. Done.!!

Comment: yes, in `.cs` file i have the code which i have shared with you

Comment: i get this error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ,i have added this `var transform = img.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform; ` and inside `if width > height` transform.Rotation = 90;

Comment: you forgot to initialize composite transform. First initilize composite transform then set it to image.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer for what you have told me to try `Add CompositeTransform transform = new CompositeTransform(); ...`

Comment: I tried your solution the image is not displaying at all, or it might be moved out of screen

Comment: Its working perfect for me. Have you added image control to grid. Coz you haven't did it in your edited code.

Comment: Yes i have added this grid.Children.Add(img);

Comment: I am doing this `img.ActualWidth > img.ActualHeight ` but both the values are 0.

Comment: ohhh...thats the culprit. until unless u load the image its ActualHeight ActualWidth will remain 0. You need to provide height width. If you have them if not then need to think workaround for that also.

Answer (score 0):

To get the width and height of the Image,

```
double height = image1.ActualHeight;
double width = image1.ActualWidth;
```